# "A member of" vs. "a member at"

Tags: word-choice, grammaticality, prepositions

Which one is correct? For example:

> - I am a member **of** Riverside Tennis Club.
> - I am a member **at** Riverside Tennis Club.

Answer (score 2):

If you look up *[member](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/member)* in almost any dictionary, all of their usage examples use *member of* something or another.

If you run a search of *member of* vs *member at* in [Google's Ngram viewer](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=member%20of,member%20at&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=), you will find that standard writing prefers *member of*; there are effectively **no** instances of *member at* in the corpus.

So you would say, "I am a *member of* the Riverside Tennis Club." You might use *at* to clarify, "I am a *member of* the Riverside Tennis Club *at* their Granite Bay location."

Answer (score 1):

The first is more idiomatic and the correct one. The second connotes that the club is a place where you are a member, less idiomatic but would still pass muster in a proper context.